# Two javascript functions not working as same way

Tags: javascript

I have written 2 javascript function but they are not working as same.

`console.log(func2());` is undefined. Can anyone tell me why and how to solve this?

```js
function func1()
{
  return {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}

function func2()
{
  return
  {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}

console.log(func1());
console.log(func2());
```

Comment: @Amadan: Good find on the dupe, goes on my list.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You have a list? Is it public? :) There's times I just know there has to be a dupe and yet I can't find a good one.

Comment: @Amadan: I do have an informal one, I just keep it in bookmarks. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion). **Never** put a newline after `return` and prior to what you want to return, it's treated as though it terminates the `return` statement (e.g., a `;` is inserted after `return`), and your function ends up effectively returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one. It's semicolon insertion. func2 is translated to

```
function func2()
{
  return;
  {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}
```

And return `undefine`.